# OVH+Proxmox: How to use packer to build Proxmox image with Fallover IP as DHCP?

Tags: debian, proxmox, ovh

I searched entire internet haven't see any solution for it yet.

I have a OVH + Proxmox instance. Plan to automatic the launch VM process. I know I can try use cloud-init but since I use Packer + (maybe) Terraform for the ESXi at home, so I want to try to use same thing for the Proxmox cloud as well.

Current setup:

- I have `packer.json`, well configured.
- I have a `debian-preseed.cfg`.

When install ESXi, the `preseed.cfg` was hosted locally and use private ip. Which works well.

However, the Proxmox on OVH can't reach my local preseed, so I decide to host it on AWS S3. Then that's when the issue concurred.

**Issue: the VM building Proxmox image can't reach the preseed file on AWS - `https://bucket-name.s3.regions.amazonaws.com/dir/debian-preseed.cfg`**

I spent few hours try to figure out what's the root cause. It seems like the VM's network isn't configured properly.

I am using DHCP + Mac-To-Static IP to make installation process easier. I am pretty sure it works if I manually install the VM. However, it seems like the IP and network only reachable after debian installation?

Is there any reason this doesn't work? Should I switch to use bridge+private IP first then manually setup the public IP later once I am using it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might lie in (un)predictable network interfaces.

The image might have in `/etc/network/interfaces` something like:

```
auto ens4
iface ens4 inet dhcp
    mtu 1500
```

Which might work on local or might not work when deployed elsewhere.

When building a VM image you could disable (un)predictable network interfaces

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

and assume that your single interface will be named `eth0`.

OVH is also using Packer for building images, but `cloud-init` as well.

`cloud-init` on first run

1. sets hostname, see `/var/lib/cloud/data/set-hostname`
2. updates `/etc/hosts`
3. attempts to configure networking (see e.g. `/etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init`)
4. removes `/var/lib/cloud/data/no-net`

This approach makes sense when you can't predict interfaces naming at the time of building VM image.